# Proof for a Limit of a Sequence converging to 0

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

$\frac{1}{n+1}$ - $\frac{1}{n+2}$ + . . . $\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{2n}$  converges to Zero.

My guess

It can be written as $\frac{1}{n}$$\sum_{k=1}^n$$\frac{1}{1+\frac{k}{n} }$  - $\frac{2}{n}$$\sum_{k=1}^{n/2}$$\frac{1}{1+\frac{2k}{n} }$

= $\frac{1}{n}$$\sum_{k=1}^n$$\frac{1}{1+\frac{k}{n} }$  - $\frac{1}{n/2}$$\sum_{k=1}^{n/2}$$\frac{1}{1+\frac{k}{n/2} }$

As n tends to infinity both sum converges to log2
Thus log2 - log2 = 0

Correct me if I assumed anything wrong. Or give something new , better way,

Comment: You cannot use this argument with alternating series, since you can do all kinds of groupings, resulting in different answers. E.g., the sequence $1,-1,1,-1,\ldots$ can be grouped to converge to $1$ or to $0$...

Comment: The accurate term here is not "series" but "sequence". This sequence is obtained by subtracting two partial sums of a series (converging indeed to ln$2$.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The analysis in the OP is not quite correct.  Instead, we have

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k+n}&=\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor} \left(\frac1{2k-1+n}-\frac1{2k+n}\right)+O\left(\frac1n\right)\\\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor} \frac1{(2k-1+n)(2k+n)}+O\left(\frac1n\right)\\\\
&\le \frac{n}{2}\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)}+O\left(\frac1n\right)
\end{align}$$

Can you finish now?